# SwipeRefreshLayout Got Action_Move freezes view

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer, drawerlayout, swiperefreshlayout

I have a normal NavigationDrawer with different fragments :

- News
- other Stuff 1
- other Stuff 2
- Setting

**The problem :**

The NewsFragment contains a SwipeRefreshLayout. It works great the first time I refresh.

I can change fragment to other Stuff 1 and 2 and Setting. So I come back to NewsFragment.

And now when I refresh, the fragment freezes.

The drawerLayout works correctly (open/close, even the ActionBar Title change) but the main fragment stay at NewsFragment and I can't scroll. But the scollListner works (I have log) but the view doesn"t change.

No refreshView (top of the swipeRefreshLayout), no scroll, no responding button (on focus, onclick) but only visually.

Actually, it's like a Responding Fragment is behind the frozen fragment.

Also I have this error in ADBLog :

```
SwipeRefreshLayout﹕ Got ACTION_MOVE event but don't have an active pointer id.
```

Any idea ??

I can post code if you ask.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ok I found the solution. I post it because it can happen to everybody and that's a little boring (two days to find for me).

First I had this in my XML which contains the SwipeRefreshLayout (a fragment):

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/news_container_refresh"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="5dp"
android:background="@color/news_background">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/news_list_recycle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:dividerHeight="5dp" />


    <ProgressBar
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/news_progress"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

**So, to fix the bug, YOU NEED TO JUST HAVE THE RECYCLEVIEW (or listview) IN YOUR SWIPEREFRESHLAYOUT :**

So, I Move my progressBar and make the RelativeLayout as the rootView.

Result :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ProgressBar
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/news_progress"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/news_container_refresh"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:background="@color/news_background">


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/news_list_recycle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:dividerHeight="5dp" />

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

I hope it will help someone else later.

Comment: I have an `Activity` with a `NavigationDrawer` that loads a `Fragment` that contains only that: a `ListView` inside a `SwipeRefreshLayout` and I have this bug too...

Comment: Nop, but I'm looking for what differs because it works for you, so I guess my error is somewhere near.

Comment: Can you publish your xml ? is your Fragment freezing like me ?

Comment: I got it to work. No need for me to post my layout, my issue was actually different from this one. Thanks anyway.

Comment: This worked for me. Make sure your RecyclerViews height is set to wrap_content also and is NOT the root view in your layout

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27073879/1983904) worked for me. It's about clearing up the refresh layout in onPause().

Answer (score -1):

Your code example does indeed fix the issue. This seems to be a problem with the v21 support library.

For a little more clarification to help others that might come across this, the issue seems to be that the `SwipeRefreshLayout` is no longer happy being the root view.

Adding a `RelativeLayout` to wrap the `SwipeRefreshLayout` fixes the bug in your case, rather than just having the `ListView/RecyclerView` inside the `SwipeRefreshLayout`. I've not tried, but I'm guessing a `LinearLayout` or other would also fix things.

So the fix is:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent">
                    <!-- List, Layout etc -->
        </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Didn't fix it for me, I changed my setup from this: Fragment -> SwipeRefresh -> Recycler to this Fragment -> FrameLayout -> SwipeRefresh -> Recycler but I still get that error.