# FragmentTransaction.remove() not removing fragment only while SwipeRefreshLayout is active

Tags: android, android-fragments, swiperefreshlayout

**The gist of my problem:**

I have multiple fragments that are added sequentially and not re-ordered. Almost all of them have SwipeRefreshLayouts as their root views. When the user triggers onBackPressed, the last fragment should be removed. If a new fragment is opened, the last fragment is hidden.

In the event that the SwipeRefreshLayout is active (ie refresh state set to **true** and onRefresh is called) and the user pops off the current fragment, the view remains stuck until an app restart. I've confirmed that onPause() and onDestroy() do get called. I have tested this across each type of my fragments, so I'm nearly sure the problem lies in how I remove fragments.

**My code:**

```
//I know this is a misnomer. I just changed the inside from 
//addToBackStack which got me the same effect
protected void addToBackStack(BaseFragment fragment){
    FragmentTransaction ft = fragMan.beginTransaction();
    if(fragCount > 0)
        ft.hide(peekBackStack());
    ft.add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment, Integer.toString(fragCount++)).commit();
    invalidateOptionsMenu();
}

protected BaseFragment peekBackStack(){
    return (BaseFragment)(fragMan.findFragmentByTag(Integer.toString(fragCount - 1)));
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
    if (fragCount <= 1) {
        //...do stuff & finish
    } else {
        BaseFragment fragment = peekBackStack();
        if(fragment != null) {
            if (fragment.isWeb() && ((WebFragment) fragment).canGoBack())
                ((WebFragment) fragment).goBack();
            else
                popActive();
        }
        else
            finish();
    }
}

public void popActive(){
    BaseFragment remove = peekBackStack();
    fragCount--;
    BaseFragment show = peekBackStack();
    fragMan.beginTransaction().remove(remove).commit();
    Log.d(TAG, ""+remove.isVisible());
    fragMan.beginTransaction().show(show).commitNow();
    show.initAppBar();
}
```

**Inside BaseFragment.java**

```
@Override
@NonNull
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                         @Nullable Bundle state){
    ViewGroup root = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(getLayoutResource(), container, false);
    if(root instanceof SwipeRefreshLayout) {
        swipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) root;
        swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);
    }
    return root;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();
    if(swipeRefreshLayout != null)
        swipeRefreshLayout.destroyDrawingCache();
}
...
```

**WebFragment XML:**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh_submission_link"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<com.github.ksoichiro.android.observablescrollview.ObservableWebView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/observable_web"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
    android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"
    android:fadeScrollbars="true">

</com.github.ksoichiro.android.observablescrollview.ObservableWebView>
```

**Main activity XML:**

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appbarLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            ...
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/appbarLayout">
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

So I found a [related thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27057449/when-switch-fragment-with-swiperefreshlayout-during-refreshing-fragment-freezes?rq=1) after hours of searching. Both solutions worked for me, although I think I prefer the FrameLayout wrapper for now. This seems to be a bug in android itself