# FlyOut menu design issue when adding fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, layout, xamarin, fragment

I'm trying to have my flyout menu working when adding fragment.
So, I have a flyout menu working thanks to this code:

https://github.com/garuma/FlyOutMenu/tree/master/FlyOutMenu

```
    <com.myApp.FlyOutContainer xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         android:id="@+id/FlyOutContainer">
         <include
              layout="@layout/menu_layout"
              android:id="@+id/menu_layout" />
         <include
              layout="@layout/content_layout"
              android:id="@+id/content_layout" />
    </comm.myApp.FlyOutContainer>
```

At the start of my application, the `content_layout` is composed of this layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <include
        layout="@layout/top_bar_layout"
        android:id="@+id/top_bar_layout" />
    <include
        layout="@layout/root_layout"
        android:id="@+id/root_layout" />
</LinearLayout>
```

After start, my activity add a fragment in the root_layout:

```
    // Create new fragment and transaction
    Fragment questionListFragment = new QuestionListFragment();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();

    transaction.Add(Resource.Id.root_layout, questionListFragment);
    // Commit the transaction
    transaction.Commit();
```

This new fragment contains a swipe to refresh layout and a list view.
When I swipe from the left to the right, the menu appears well. But to hide it (swipe from the right to the left), the menu in background.

**Update:**

I think the problem is on notifyDataSetChanged. My view isn't centered when the menu is open, and I update my listview. So when updating, my view is re-created and re-centered and the menu stay in background...
How can I fix it ?

Here are screenshot to understand:
(I can't post image on stackOverflow yet and no more than 2 links...)

Here is the problem:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using the standard navigation draw. You can find my examples here: https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/Xam.NavDrawer

Comment: Thanks for your answer @JamesMontemagno, I think my problem comes from my SwipeRefreshLayout. When I disable it, all works perfectly. In the output, I have : `[SwipeRefreshLayout] Got ACTION_MOVE event but don't have an active pointer id.`
Maybe the same problem here: [swiperefreshlayout got action move freezes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26973679/swiperefreshlayout-got-action-move-freezes-view)